# How to verify php script authenticity via CDN online service?

Tags: php, cdn, wordpress, password-protection, verification

E.g. I am selling a WordPress or Joomla plugin and after the user installs and activates this plugin, but it still remains not vworking, because he needs to click on some "verify" button so the status of the plugin changes to became working.

This button will trigger a function that will connect to some "service" where I will previously add his website URL e.g. `http://myclientsweb.com` plus maybe some verification code attached in the url matched with the data on my serrver, the status of the plugin change to activated.

I can do the programming stuff on both sides (client's web and server for verification) basically, but the problem is I need some solution as  server where verification urls and codes are stored is available all the time , something like CDN, so even one server is off, the client can always verify his plugin somwhere else.

So, the best solution would be some kind of CDN service that specialize for that. It could be free or paid. Do you know about something of that nature? Or do you suggest some better solution?

Comment: Anybody with some solution?

Comment: It's not really programming related. You'd probably have more luck asking this on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking you need something else than a CDN for that purpose. I would suggest you look to the cloud for a solution. I think, if you want the most uptime for your verification app, with the simplicity of a CDN, you should go for something like [Pagodabox](https://pagodabox.com/) or [Heroku](https://get.heroku.com/).
Those two services host your code for you, much like a regular server, but they automaticly scale and handle requests. I theory it should make your app available 100% of the time, with minimal resources spent from you.

Both services offer free plans to get going, and test out if it's something for you.

I hope this helps, this is my suggestion to your problem at least.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking about switching to Node.js instead of PHP for the new version of my app, so this could be a solution. Thanks for an idea. Happy helping ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your server host is good, they usually offer 99% up time guarantee. CDN is required if you are getting large number of verification requests causing delay in processing.

Here, I would suggest, when someone tries to verify plugin and if server is down (couldn't reply), send an email to admin (you). So that you instantly know that the server is down and you can manually process the verification.

Answer (score 0):

CDN stands for content delivery network a large distributed system. Which is mostly used to serve content. And does not seem to fit what you are looking for. If i understand correctly you are looking to offer 99.x% uptime. So client can always register their plugins.

This could require settings up multiple virtual hosts / dedicated servers behind a load balancer. In that way when one node goes down. The load balancer could redirect the traffic to a new node to handle requests. You really need to find a good hosting company. That's all!